# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

I am getting an error as below on my Angular 6.0.8 application. I am using Angular CLI and running from VSCode.

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(72,67):
>   error TS1144: '{' or '; ' expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or stat ement expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33):
>   error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39):
>   error TS1109: Expression expecte d.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or stat ement expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(80,1): error TS1128: Declaration or stat ement expected.

Using the following version in application,

```
 "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
 "typescript": "~2.7.2"
 "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.4",
 "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
```

[image]

Please help me to sort out this !!

Comment: what's your rxjs version ?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.2.1",

Comment: please first try to upgrade to the new version of @angular/flex-layout, to do that change `^6.0.0-beta.17` to `^6.0.0-beta.18` and run `npm cache clean --force
` and run `npm install` and see if that fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried but same issue

Comment: i had the same issue, so i uninstalled version 6.0.0-beta.18 and install de version 6.0.0-beta.16 and solve the problem o/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading typescript to 2.9.2 . Works for me with flex-layout 6.0.0-beta.18 and rxjs 6.3.2.

I think this is the [Issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/831) in flex-layout.

Answer (score 3):

Revert to `6.2.2` version of `RxJS` to fix the build.

for further information please see: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/827